# I can't stream videos anymore

Tags: video, streaming, youtube, video-streaming

I can't stream videos anymore. Suddenly, without installing anything or changing anything I stopped being able to stream any videos. I have an Ad blocker on and a tracking site blocker as well. Both of them were installed LONG before I was unable to stream anything. 1 day back I suddenly became unable to stream anything. Including Pandora, Youtube, Vimeo :(

My laptop is on the same network and can stream videos normally.

Comment: Have you tried disabling your security software temporarily to see if it makes any difference?

Comment: Yes it makes no difference. I tried to disable everything and it didn't help at all!

Comment: It literally happened suddenly, without me changing anything.

Comment: Did you restart your computer meanwhile? Rebooting can fix problems related to drivers and hardware acceleration.

Comment: Yeah I have done that about 4 times since this incident happened.

Comment: I know this information doesn't help much but I was looking forward for people telling me that flash or something auto-updated itself and there is a bug or something. Because I don't think it is related to anything I have done. :(((((((

Comment: First, update your graphics card driver, if it doesn't help install K-Lite Codec Pack and it should solve the problem.

Comment: While going through Google Reader, I clicked on a video to play forgetting I wasn't able to do that. I got an error regarding VM_STREAM_NO_CONNECTION (That wasn't the exact message but the closest match) I am in the process of installing a new driver.

Comment: I am able to play downloaded videos.

Comment: Also I did what u said and the problem is still there.

Comment: Is it with just 1 browser or no browser is able to stream ?

Comment: I also believe it might have to do with flash or another plugin upgrading itself in the background. Test other browsers and maybe reinstall flash.

Comment: I tried linux on vmware box and it has the same problem. I tried different browsers. It has the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like Flash Player has been removed. Please check if you have both 32 and 64 bit versions just in case. Also I would put Pandora and the rest into a white list.

Answer (score 0):

The Adobe Flash player was EOL on 12/31/2020.  Your browser is not likely using Adobe Flash's plugin to play videos on major streaming sites.  If you have Flash or any Pepper plugins trying to play video, try removing the plugins and see if that helps.  It is outdated advice to "check your Flash plugin".

If you tried a Linux VM in bridged mode (not NAT mode) and are still having problems, but not having problems on another laptop while on the same network:

- Confirm the issue still happens with your ad blocker/tracking blocker disabled.  If disabling it fixes, reinstall and update these programs.
- Try [uninstalling then reinstalling](https://kb.wisc.edu/helpdesk/page.php?id=58029) your network adapter.
- Try [creating a new user account](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/create-a-user-account-in-windows-4fac6fd5-74c0-9737-69b8-6e77e00422dc) and see if the problem follows.  If it is fixed, you can move your data over to the new account, or try [resetting the PC](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-reset-windows-11-pc-factory-settings) after backing up your data and making sure you can reinstall any apps you use.